# Perl modules to use for parallel processing

Tags: multithreading, perl

I want to parallelize a program written in Perl.

The code loops over multiple files and calls a subroutine for each file.

I also need to share some read only local data structures with the subroutine.

```
   sub process_in_parallel {

      my $readOnlySchema = foo();

      foreach my $file ( @files ) {

          validate_the_file($file,$readOnlySchema);
      }
```

What are the Perl modules that the perl monks can recommend for this scenario. I tried some of the following:

- `threads`

  The problem with this is managing the threads. Is there an efficient thread manager or thread pool library that can help me with this? I am also not sure if I can share the read only object.
- `Parallel::ForkManager`

  The problem with this is that it forks processes rather than threads and is increasing the time of execution in my case.

I have the same question posted here : http://perlmonks.com/?node_id=1182517

Comment: Check out [MultiThread](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/MultiThread/lib/MultiThread.pm) module.

Comment: If you want to work with threads, use [Thread::Queue](http://p3rl.org/Thread::Queue). Checking the [MCE](http://p3rl.org/MCE) namespace might also give you some possibilities.

Comment: I have toned down your question a little but you are still asking for recommendations. Such questions are off topic for Stack Overflow and your question will probably be closed. If you edit it to ask more specific questions then you may be able to keep it alive.

Comment: By the way, we are not the Perl Monks. If you have cross-posted this question then you must say so, giving a link to the foreign site. Otherwise people on either side will waste their time answering a question that already has an answer elsewhere.

Comment: Your Perl code will not compile.

Comment: When cross posting, tell both parties, so nobody is wasting their time: http://perlmonks.com/?node_id=1182517

Comment: @ChankeyPathak Did you suggest MultiThread based on knowing (maybe using) it? The metacpan listing shows its version being stuck at 0.9 since the last update in 2008, it's not been ++ed, and the cpantesters matrix shows no results for any platform except linux (with fails on that for several perl versions). (Maybe you could encourage its author to update?) Thread::Queue in contrast shows version 3.12, last update 5 days ago, 6 ++ed, a 5 star review for v3.07, a bugs/limits section that looks the part, and a cpantesters matrix awash with green. The MCE namespace totally looks the part too.

Comment: *"`Parallel::ForkManager` The problem with this is that it forks processes rather than threads and is increasing the time of execution in my case."* In general, forking is not a problem; if you're on *nix, it's highly optimized (Windows is another matter). You should show your Parallel::ForkManager code so we can help you figure out why it's slow.